# Is it possible to set z-index independently in another z-indexed element?

Tags: html, css

I have some images with small menu at the bottom. They are positioned absolute so that they can overlap each other. I'm using z-index (which is manipulated by some javascript code) to determine by the user which image is displayed first on top of the second.

However, I need the menu to be displayed in the foreground, regardless of the z-indexed element they are in.

Simplified code structure:

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

#child1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#child2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <img src="source" alt="img" />
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>


  <div id="child2">
    <img src="source" alt="img" />
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I set the menu element very high z-index, it's still presented behind the child2 image. The reason I'm using such html structure is that every child element is wrapped in moveable component that can be dragged and dropped.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

// edit

I'm using VueJS and Moveable [components](https://github.com/probil/vue-moveable), that are returned using loop.

The Moveable component has zIndex based on `depth` variable, so that it has the ability to be displayed on top of other image.
What I want to do is to have the menu div with highest z-index as possible, so that once it's displayed (because it's hidden by default - clicking on the image activates the menu), it shows up in foreground of all the images.

```css
.menu {
    min-width: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 6px;
    bottom: -70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 0.625rem 0.875rem;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<Moveable
    v-bind="moveable"
    class="moveable target"
    :style="`width:${image.width}px; height:${image.height}px; zIndex: ${image.depth}`"
    @click.native="handleClick"
    @drag="(transforms) => { handleDrag(transforms, image) }"
    @resize="(transforms) => { handleResize(transforms, image) }"
    @scale="(transforms) => { handleScale(transforms, image) }"
    @scaleEnd="(transforms) => { handleScaleEnd(transforms, image) }"
    @resizeEnd="(transforms) => { handleResizeEnd(transforms, image) }"
    @rotate="handleRotate"
    @warp="handleWarp"
    ref="moveable"
  >
    <img
      :src="image.src"
    >
    <div v-if="guideVisible" class="menu">
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            elevation="3"
            class="menu-button"
            @click="handleFlipToFront"
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            icon
          >
            <v-icon>{{ flipFrontIcon }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>

        </template>
        <span>Bring to front</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </div>
  </Moveable>
```

Comment: hi, give more code pls

Comment: Hi @sergeykuznetsov I added more code.

Comment: Probably worth looking carefully at the stacking contexts you are creating here. The stacking context created by child1 is separate from that created by child2 and the menu in child1 can't 'beat' the stacking context in child2 - however high the menu z-index is.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definition of z-index at w3: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

> The order in which the rendering tree is painted onto the canvas is described in terms of stacking contexts. Stacking contexts can contain further stacking contexts. A stacking context is atomic from the point of view of its parent stacking context; boxes in other stacking contexts may not come between any of its boxes.

Whenever you give an element a z-index, it will be seen as its own container with its own z-indexes. Meaning that as soon as child1 has a z-index, everything inside child1 (in your case menu) can only influence whether to be on top or below any other views inside child1.

---

A way to overcome this issue in your case would be to find a way to make it work without the z-index on the children so your menu's can still use z-index to render over everything. A way would be to just use the order of how it is defined in the tree.

Also from w3:

> Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

And since you're using Vue it should just be a matter of moving the focussed item to the end of the list and let Vue do the re-rendering.